# Convert JSON value by SQL query

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a JSON data in a field and I want to query base on one of the JSON columns but I receive converting error.
I try these method but I receive convert error
This is original query:

```
select * 
from TableName 
where json_value([Data],'$.Group.Field' ) >= 1.1
```

and this is custom query:

```
select *  
from TableName 
where cast(JSON_VALUE([Data],'$.Group.Field') as decimal) <> ''
```

this is another one:

```
select *  
from TableName 
where convert(decimal, json_value([Data], '$.Group.Field')) > 1.1
```

but I get error with all of them:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

this is JSON schema:

```json
{
  "Group": {
    "Field": "1.1"
  },
  "Group2": {
    "Field2": "1.1"
  },
  "Group3": {
    "Field3": "1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Well - what does your JSON look like? We can't really just **guess** what could be wrong - we need to see all the relevant info to help you ....

Comment: @marc_s sorry . I added json schema

Comment: `decimal` without any further info is equivalent to `decimal(18,0)` --> no digits after the decimal point. But your JSON does have fractional values - so try using `decimal(20,4)` or something like that instead of just `decimal` in your conversions

Comment: @marc_s same error . I use float function and it's not work

Comment: Is that the only JSON in the table? Seems like you would get that error message if there was a row containing something like `'{"Group":{"Field":"Z"}}'`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning in my table I have some control filed like modify time or something else. but main filed is a nvarchar filed that contain is this json in string format

Comment: If you remove the quotes around the number in the Json payload, i.e. change ```"Field":"1.1"``` to ```"Field":1.1```, does that have any impact?

Comment: Please edit this fiddle *(and add the resulting link  to your question)* to demonstrate what your issue is: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fe4e2ca54703c7daf9e6ea68fba9ed75

Comment: It's almost certain that some of your rows contain JSON whose `$.Group.Field` values cannot be converted to decimal. Consider using the [`try_cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql) and [`try_convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) functions which will return `null` for invalid inputs instead of throwing an error message.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I use this command to filter non valid data : ISNUMERIC(json_value([Data],'$.Group.Field' ))=1

Comment: The ISNUMERIC function is not reliable. e.g. `select isnumeric('1,2.3');` returns 1.

Comment: @MatBailie interesting . your sample work correctly. but my work on real engine has error !

Comment: @iman Then the difference is either the rest of your query, or the data (possibly in other rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `JSON_VALUE()` is of type `nvarchar(4000)`, so if you want to compare the `$.Group.Field` part of the stored JSON use `TRY_CONVERT()` for explicit conversion:

```
SELECT *  
FROM TableName 
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(numeric(10, 1), JSON_VALUE([Data], '$.Group.Field')) > 1.1
```

If you want to parse the whole JSON, the following approach is an option:

Sample data:

```
SELECT *
INTO TableName
FROM (VALUES
   ('{
  "Group": {
    "Field": "1.2"
  },
  "Group2": {
    "Field2": "x.1"
  },
  "Group3": {
    "Field3": "1.1"
  }
}')
) v (Data)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT t.*, j.[key] AS GroupId
FROM TableName t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.Data) j
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(numeric(10, 1), JSON_VALUE(j.[value], '$.Field')) > 1.1
```

Result:

| Data | GroupId |
| --- | --- |
| {"Group": {"Field": "1.2"},"Group2": {"Field2": "x.1"},"Group3": {"Field3": "1.1"}} | Group |